# Dependence between two continuous time Markov jump processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let $(X^1_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be an Ito process driven by a Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$.

Let $N\ge 2$ and $Q_{nm} : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ be jump intensities depending on $X^1$ and consider a continuous time Markov jump process $(Y^1_t)_{t\ge 0}$ taking values in $\{1,\dots,N\}$ such that
$$ \mathbb{P}(Y^1_{t+dt} = n \mid X^1_t, Y^1_t) = Q_{Y^1_tn}(X^1_t)dt + o(dt),\ n\neq Y_t.$$

My first question is if such process $Y^1$ is unique and how do we construct it?

Now let $(X^2_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be an other Ito process driven by the same Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$, and $(Y^2_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be continuous Markov jump process with values in $\{1,\dots,N\}$ such that
$$ \mathbb{P}(Y^2_{t+dt} = n \mid X^2_t, Y^2_t) = Q_{Y^2_tn}(X^2_t)dt + o(dt),\ n\neq Y_t.$$

My second question what is the dependence of $Y^1$ and $Y^2$ ?

My last question is if there a simple integration formula to obtain an estimate like
$$ \mathbb{E}((Y^1_T - Y^2_T)^2)\le \mathbb{E}((Y^1_0 - Y^2_0)^2) + C\int_0^T\mathbb{E}((X^1_t-X^2_t)^2) + \mathbb{E}((Y^1_t-Y^2_t)^2) dt.$$

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried any ideas for your first question? One idea might be to define jump times recursively. For the second question, I might be wrong, but I do not think that you can say something in this generality.

Comment: Existence is OK: given $X_t$, $(Y_s)_{s\ge t}$ is a usual continuous time Markov chain, that you can construct with exponential waiting time (with parameter depending on $X_t$).

Comment: For the uniqueness question, you can probably condition on the whole process $X^1$. In this quenched form, $Y$ is simply an continuous-time inhomogeneous Markov chain (that could be made time homogeneous by considering $(Y_t, t)$ instead). So, as long as the process is unique [this probably depends on the properties of $Q$], then $(X,Y)$ is too. Another approach is to go to the martingale formulation in which case you might want to look at Ethier&Kurtz 1986, Problem 4.11.3 or the section on perturbations. But then again, the material is very heavy to get into...

Comment: For your last question, note that the dependence of $Y^1$ and $Y^2$ depends heavily on whether the additional driving noises are dependent or not. You only assume that the basic driving noise of $X$ is identical.

Comment: Exactly! But I was confused how to write this underlying jump process. For X^1 and X^2 the underlying process is the Brownian motion. But for Y^1 and Y^2 how can I "define" it? Can I write it with a Poisson process? Is there a equivalent of the Ito formula for such process?